# Laravel query builder whereRaw with convert to datatype returning different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, binary, query-builder

Here I have two similar queries that return the same result if I paste them directly on SMSS:

[image]

But when using Laravel's query builder I get different results:

```
//select count(*) from [tbl_rfaccount] where CONVERT(varchar, id) = 'test'
$count = DB::connection('sqlsrv_rf_user')->table('tbl_rfaccount')
  ->whereRaw("CONVERT(varchar, id) = ?", $request->input('username'))
  ->count();
//$count = 1

//select count(*) from [tbl_rfaccount] where id = CONVERT(binary(13), 'test')
$count = DB::connection('sqlsrv_rf_user')->table('tbl_rfaccount')
  ->whereRaw("id = CONVERT(binary(13), ?)", $request->input('username'))
  ->count();
//$count = 0
```

Why is that? I've using Laravel Telescope and the queries look exactly like those I ran on SSMS.

This is how the table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please post queries and data as formatted text *not* images.

Comment: @DaleK I did post them as text.

Comment: Um, no, I'm referring to the 2 images in your question.

Comment: Just a Note:  Always best to include a length when defining a varchar or nvarchar i.e varchar(50)

Comment: Is this a case caused by ascii vs. unicode values? Seems most languages will inherently use unicode strings. Your pure tsql example uses only ascii strings.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with SMor. Seems like collation settings are not matching between database and Laravel, or Laravel is trying to send through `nvarchar` values for some reason. Notice how the following return different results: `select convert(binary(13), 'test'), convert(binary(13), N'test')`

Comment: My SQL database has the collation set to `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`. I went to my database connection on Laravel and added `'collation' => 'Cyrillic_General_CI_AS'` but the problem persists.